# how to get current location of user in IntentService in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager

This what i'm trying to do.
I have main Activity calling BroadcastReceiver name SmsAlarmReceiver.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SmsAlarmReceiver.ALARM_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Now my SmsAlarmReceiver.java looks like:

```
public class SmsAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

LocationManager locationmanager;
public static final String ALARM_ACTION= "com.example.finaltracking.SMS_REC";
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationmanager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent smsintent = new Intent(context,SmsService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, smsintent, 0);
    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1*60*1000,10,pendingintent);
}
```

}

So in this receiver i am requesting for location updates using pendingIntent to listen to location change.

My service named SmsService.java looks like:

```
public class SmsService extends IntentService {

public SmsService(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Location location = (Location) bundle.get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    Log.d("msg", "Loc is " + location.getLatitude() +","+ location.getLongitude());
    sendMessage("983******","msg is " + location.getLatitude()+"," +location.getLongitude());
}

private void sendMessage(String rec,String msg){

    //PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,MainActivity.class),0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(msg);
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(rec,null, parts,null, null);
}


  }
```

My app is not force closing but it is not able to send the message to receiver specified.

Is there any better alternative to this problem.In short i want to implement feature that sends GPS location of User every 5 minutes once user has enabled tracking feature.How can i implement this using services/Intent Services/Broadcast Receivers.?Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called **[CWAC Location Poller: Finding Your Location Periodically](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)**

and improved version of it https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll

Some simpler version

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: i have already gone through it but being a newbie in Java/Android development i am not getting the code written in that repo.Is there any other way i could work this out?>

Comment: I know the basics but what i am asking is that why does requestlocationupdates doesn't work in Services the way they work in Activities..

Comment: @Droidwala could you just post code here how exactly you implemented it? thankx

Comment: @ndeokar I implemented this few years back.So,i don't quite remember what i implemented back then.But as much i can recollect i went with first link posted in the above answer and modified it according to my requirement..that being said a lot has changed from past couple of years on how to fetch periodic locations..

Comment: First link is dead